# How to disable strict host key checking in ssh?

Tags: ssh

I would like to disable strict host key checking in `ssh` for Ubuntu 11.04. How to do it?

Comment: Hi karthick87, I hope you understand the security implications of making that change ;)

Comment: It should be noted however, that you **want** to know if a host key has *changed*. That is a big red flag that someone may be spoofing the host. So UserKnownHostFile /dev/null is a really bad idea.

Comment: SSH is used not only for remote connections, you know. All hosts I'm connecting to are in heap on my table and share the same IP, so I always have the new host warning.

Comment: If you just want to remove the message for a particular host, delete the corresponding line ~/.ssh/known_hosts.

Comment: If you just need to do a one-time connect without errors: `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`

Comment: Thanks @odinho-Velmont, I needed to do this when reverse tunneling from several different hosts to the same local port (one at a time, of course).  Without this, the server complains when connecting using the same credentials to the different servers.

Comment: Of course there are valid reasons for this question, but the warning being prominent helps protect people when they come to this page for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 366, accepted):

In your `~/.ssh/config` (if this file doesn't exist, just create it):

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

This will turn it off for all hosts you connect to. You can replace the `*` with a hostname pattern if you only want it to apply to some hosts.

Make sure the permissions on the file restrict access to yourself only:

```
sudo chmod 400 ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: Make one - the entire contents of the file are in my quote above. Note it's in the `.ssh` subdirectory of your homedir as well.

Comment: Is the indentation required? My entries look like blocks divided by a
empty line.

Comment: This is unwise in many cases, often you just want to disable it once: `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`

Comment: mkdir -p ~/.ssh && echo "Host *" > ~/.ssh/config && echo " StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config

Comment: Awesome, I was stuck in fixing ~/.ssh/known_hosts but it never existed. Luckily I found this thread and can log in now. I'm just wondering how can i log in to other machine but not just one specific type of machine which i launched by shared ami from another aws account. Thanks

Comment: I think chmod 600 is enough

Comment: It should be noted that host keys still get added to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` even with `StrictHostKeyChecking` set to `no`.

Comment: doesn't work, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462362/for-ssh-command-line-tool-why-is-stricthostkeychecking-no-not-effective

Answer (score 357):

Rather than adding it to your `~/.ssh/config` file for all Host *, it would be a safer to specify a particular host.

You can also pass a parameter on the command-line like this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no yourHardenedHost.com
```

This will automatically add the host key to your known_hosts file if it's not already there.

If there's a mismatch, it will display a big warning and not update known_hosts.  It will also disable password-based authentication to prevent MITM attacks.  Private key authentication will still automatically get through though, which you may not want.

Comment: Note that you generally only need to do this once per host since it says this the first time: `Warning: Permanently added 'frxxx.blaps.net,10.11.12.13' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.`

Comment: That won't work. It should be `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` instead.

Comment: @qwertzguy It does work. Your option will make it so that the host key is lost each time, which is useful and more secure, but not what the question asked for.

Comment: @qwertzguy Could you add this as an answer, yours is really the best for quick'n'dirty "just connect I know what I'm doing"? Didn't wanna ninja-steal your answer.

Comment: @odinho-velmont done

Comment: use both works for me,  ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no

Comment: Fun fact: When using SFTP, using `-o whatever` precludes the use of `user@host` notation for determining which user to connect as.

Comment: I don't use `sftp` much, but it worked same way for me on MacOS, Debian, and FreeBSD when I tried them today. What distro are you using?

Comment: I wish there was a way to add multiple host keys for a single host - if we have multiple fixed hosts behind a load balancer, I know which hosts to expect, but I can't ssh directly to said hosts.  For now I do the above to disable strict host checking...

Comment: It should be noted that host keys still get added to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` even with `StrictHostKeyChecking` set to `no`.

Comment: @MarkHu To avoid show this warning just add `-o LogLevel=ERROR`

Answer (score 186):

It's worth pointing out that setting in your ssh config:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Will mean hostkeys are still added to .ssh/known_hosts - you just won't be prompted about whether you trust them, but should hosts change I'm willing to bet you'll get the big warning about it.  You can work around this problem by adding another parameter:

```
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

This will add all these "newly discovered" hosts to the trash bin.  If a host key changes, no troubles.

I would be remiss not to mention that circumventing these warnings on hostkeys has obvious security ramifications - you should be careful that you're doing it for the right reasons & that what you're connecting to actually *is* what you mean to connect to and not a malicious host, since at this point you've eroded a major part of the security in ssh as a solution.

For example if you were to try and set this with the commandline, the full command would be:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null user@host
```

That would be silly though - given that the working examples above for ssh config files is likely to make more sense in all cases.

Comment: You're correct, you do get the big warning

Comment: I think this is the right answer. This works well for connecting to hosts on a private local network.

Comment: Could be convenient to have an alias to `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostFiles=/dev/null user@host`. In my case I use `issh` to connect to hosts where I know the host key changes.

Comment: @ecerulm - just a small typo: it's `UserKnownHostsFile` not `UserKnownHostFiles`.

Comment: like a Gem, finally someone understands the generosity in completion and conclusion

Comment: When you are running this in a script in a Docker container, there is never a known_hosts file. You don't want a prompt because its unattended. The whole file system gets dumped at the end of the docker run. So the security issues don't apply.

Comment: @LeeMeador There isn't a `known_hosts` file in your Docker containers *because nobody put one there*. Not because there **can't** be one or **never** is one. There **can** be one. You can copy one in at build time, or mount one at docker run time, or fetch one from inside the container using another secure mechanism. If this security issue is important enough to your organization, then you can create a discovery and delivery system in your CI/CD processes to have an updated `known_hosts` file in your Docker images.

Comment: @ErikE Good point. Perhaps I should have said "typically not" instead of "never" but my point was actually that creating the known_hosts file on the fly in a Docker container reduces the security blast radius if the container spins down before too long. Doesn't apply to long lived containers. May or may not apply in k8s if instances are spun up and removed a lot.

Comment: If you're facing the "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" warning, you might want to try to ignore it (ssh to the server, e.g. to check if the public key is accepted, or to see what's there). Given that you're using [public key authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/why-is-using-an-ssh-key-more-secure-than-using-passwords#comment113819_69408) (don't send the password), and not using ssh agent forwarding, it should be safe. That's one use case I can think of. But you should assume you're connecting to some other server.

Answer (score 28):

FYI.  I prefer to disable host checking just when using cssh.

```
alias cssh='ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'
```

Comment: `cssh` or `ssh`?

Comment: Maybe he uses http://cssh.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Am I wrong, or is the second `-o` unnecessary?

Comment: `alias relay='ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null 11086695@172.26.19.19 -p 2222'` work for me

Answer (score 19):

If you want to disable on a one time basis use:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

That will work also if the host key changes and will make sure not to save the key as trusted for added security.

Answer (score 10):

From what it *sounds like*,

```
NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes
```

*may be* good enough, for you. AND you'd still be able to maintain that semblance of security.

Answer (score 3):

https://askubuntu.com/a/87452/129227 suggest to modify the config file which helps. But instead of opening things up for any host I wanted this to be done per host. The script below helps automating the process:

**example call**

./sshcheck somedomain site1 site2 site3

**sshcheck script**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2017-08-25
# check ssh access to bitplan servers

#ansi colors
#http://www.csc.uvic.ca/~sae/seng265/fall04/tips/s265s047-tips/bash-using-colors.html
blue='\033[0;34m'  
red='\033[0;31m'  
green='\033[0;32m' # '\e[1;32m' is too bright for white bg.
endColor='\033[0m'

#
# a colored message 
#   params:
#     1: l_color - the color of the message
#     2: l_msg - the message to display
#
color_msg() {
  local l_color="$1"
  local l_msg="$2"
  echo -e "${l_color}$l_msg${endColor}"
}

#
# error
#
#   show an error message and exit
#
#   params:
#     1: l_msg - the message to display
error() {
  local l_msg="$1"
  # use ansi red for error
  color_msg $red "Error: $l_msg" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

#
# show the usage
#
usage() {
  echo "usage: $0 domain sites"
  exit 1 
}

#
# check the given server
#
checkserver() {
  local l_server="$1"
  grep $l_server $sconfig > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 1 ]
  then
    color_msg $blue "adding $l_server to $sconfig"
    today=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
    echo "# added $today by $0"  >> $sconfig
    echo "Host $l_server" >> $sconfig
    echo "   StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> $sconfig
    echo "   userKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" >> $sconfig
    echo "" >> $sconfig
  else
    color_msg $green "$l_server found in $sconfig"
  fi
  ssh -q $l_server id > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    color_msg $green "$l_server accessible via ssh"
  else
    color_msg $red "ssh to $l_server failed" 
    color_msg $blue "shall I ssh-copy-id credentials to $l_server?"
    read answer
    case $answer in
      y|yes) ssh-copy-id $l_server
    esac
  fi
}

#
# check all servers
#
checkservers() {
me=$(hostname -f)
for server in $(echo $* | sort)
do
  os=`uname`
  case $os in
   # Mac OS X
   Darwin*)
     pingoption=" -t1";;
    *) ;;
  esac

  pingresult=$(ping $pingoption -i0.2 -c1 $server)
  echo $pingresult | grep 100 > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 1 ]
  then 
    checkserver $server
    checkserver $server.$domain
  else
    color_msg $red "ping to $server failed"
  fi
done
}

#
# check configuration
#
checkconfig() {
#https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh
  if [ -f $sconfig ]
  then
    color_msg $green "$sconfig exists"
    ls -l $sconfig
  fi
}

sconfig=~/.ssh/config

case  $# in
  0) usage ;;
  1) usage ;;
  *) 
    domain=$1 
    shift 
    color_msg $blue "checking ssh configuration for domain $domain sites $*"
    checkconfig
    checkservers $* 
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: `grep $l_server $sconfig > /dev/null; if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then` should be replaced with `if ! grep -q "$l_server" "$sconfig"; then`. 1) Don't check exit codes unless required, instead just use `if` directly. 2) grep has a `-q` option. Use it instead of `> /dev/null`. 3) All environment variable expansion should be double-quoted. Also, consider avoiding abbreviations and consider naming compound words like `checkserver` as `check_server` or `checkServer` so IDEs with spell check don't complain.

Comment: @ErikE - please post your improved version - I'll happily upvote it.

Comment: It's okay, my comment is here and anyone who wants it will find it.